# Duplicate Symbol Error - Global Variable

Tags: c, linker, linker-errors

So I have three files:

```
jarvismarch.c
jarvismarchtools.c
jarvismarchtools.h
```

After running `make`, I receive the following error:

```
Andrew-Carpenters-Laptop:Independent Study ahcarpenter$ make
cc    -c -o jarvismarch.o jarvismarch.c
cc    -c -o jarvismarchtools.o jarvismarchtools.c
cc -o jarvismarch jarvismarch.o jarvismarchtools.o
ld: duplicate symbol _string1 in jarvismarchtools.o and jarvismarch.o for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

`string 1` is declared within `jarvismarchtools.c`. `jarvismarchtools.h` is included within `jarvismarchtools.c` as well as `jarvismarch.c`.

Any ideas as to how I can resolve this error?

Within `jarvismarchtools.h`:

```
/*
    FILENAME: jarvismarchtools.h
    AUTHOR: Andrew H. Carpenter
    DATE: 2 Feb 2013
    DESCRIPTION: This is a header file containing tools for running Jarvis' March.
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

extern int string1 = 1;

typedef struct Point {
    double x, y;
    char *label;
} point;

/*
    DESCRIPTION: A function that determines the angle (in degrees) between two points.
    INPUT: Requires two points as input.
```

Within `jarvismarchtools.c`:

```
/*
    FILENAME: jarvismarchtools.c
    AUTHOR: Andrew H. Carpenter
    DATE: 2 Feb 2013
    DESCRIPTION: This is an implemenetation file containing tools for running Jarvis' March.
*/
#include "jarvismarchtools.h"

int string1 = 1;

float getAngle(point p1, point p2){
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the variable should be shared:

- Make it `extern` in the header
- Define it in one of the C files without `extern`

If the variable shouldn't be shared add a `static` in front.

Comment: So I made the changes described above yet I'm still receiving the aforementioned error. Any ideas?

Comment: @Drew Please post the modified code and the exact error message.

Comment: You might also want to add that the variable can/should only be initialized in one place.

Comment: +1 @Code-Guru - the `extern int string1 = 1` seems likely wrong.

Comment: So I posted the modified code and the most recent error message above.

Comment: Shouldn't I just have to declare `int string1 = 1;` within the header?

Comment: @Drew You should *declare* the variable in the header and not initialize it. You should *define* and initialize the variable in the .c file.

Comment: if it does not work, delete all output and recompile